# How do I make files downloadable for a particular role in Plone?

Tags: python, plone

I wish to make the contents of a folder in Plone downloadable only for certain roles. Can this be done easily? At present anybody who clicks the hyperlink for file name in the folder contents can download the file easily. I know about the site-wide option of overriding the at_download code using ZMI.

Comment: Why not just make the folder private and give the reader role to whichever users or groups needs access to the files? Is it that you need to display folder contents, but not allow individual files to be downloaded?

Comment: Exactly http://stackoverflow.com/users/624821/stevem you guessed right. I am aware of the private folder option. But as you see I want to make the download feature conditionally downloadable

Comment: How about adding workflow to the file content type (which currently inherits its parent's workflow)? It could be placeful if you don't want it throughout the site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/624821/stevem can you please  elaborate as to how inheriting workflow helps in this case? example 1 folder contains files accessible for everybody for reading and no download, other folder with files which can be downloadable

Comment: Out of the box, files and images have no workflow of their own. So, they use the containing folder's workflow. If the folder is public, the files in it are public; if it's private, the files are private. This is unlike documents, for example, which have their own workflow and may have different state than the containing folder.
The point is that you may create a workflow where files can have different states than their containers. And, you may use placeful workflow to turn it on or off in different parts of a site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/624821/stevem I got your point. Satisfies my requirement. Thank you

Comment: I'll write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codeless way to do this is to make use of Plone's workflow system.

Out-of-the-box, Plone's file and image content types do not have their own workflow. That means that files and images will simply inherit the publication state of their parent folder. This is easy and sensible, but it doesn't meet the need you're describing.

To change the situation, you may use the "types" configuration panel to turn on independent workflow for files and images. Then, their publication status may be set separately from their containing folders. Typically, you'd choose the same workflow that you're using for documents. Then, you may publish a folder and list its contents while having the files within be private -- thus requiring login for viewing.

If you need this to work differently in different places, you may turn on "placeful" workflow (turn it on by adding it in the add-ons panel; it's pre-installed, but not active). This allows different workflows in different parts of a site. It increases complexity, but is often an ideal solution to this kind of puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not so simple and you need to add some line of code in a little Plone product (no way TTW). Code snippets below are not tested.

1. Plone file are developed using the Archetypes framework (this will probably change on Plone 5). What you need to change is the `read_permission` of the `file` field (see the [Archetypes field reference](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/old/archetypes/fields/fields_reference.html)).

   from Products.Archetypes.content.file import ATFile

   ATFile.schema['file'].read_permission = 'you new permission'

The you simply need to assign your new permission to a role.

1. This could be not enough (probably step 1 is not useful nowadays). You need to perform the same operation for the `[plone.app.blob extension][2]`:

   from plone.app.blob.subtypes import SchemaExtender

   SchemaExtender.fields[0]..read_permission = 'you new permission'
2. Last one: you probably need to customize the [file_view template](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/028f82f0177fdbc4821a21950be2c1d728831113/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content/file_view.pt#L15) or an "Unauthorized" error will be raised when a user without the permission will visit the file view.